# R notebook font size

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, font-size, rnotebook

What are my options for changing the font size of dynamically-generated output, when rendering to a PDF?  My document currently looks something like this:

````
---
title: "Foo"
author: "Bar"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %e, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes: \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{color}
---

# Introduction

```{bash echo=FALSE}
perl -le 'print for 1..50'
```
````

I want to decrease the font size to help more output fit on a single page of the PDF.  I'm not currently also outputting to HTML, so a cross-format solution would be cool but not really necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as `fontsize: 12pt` (or of course `fontsize: 9pt` as we use in [pinp](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/pinp/index.html))

Modified file:

````
---
title: "Foo"
author: "Bar"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %e, %Y')`"
fontsize: 12pt
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes: \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{color}
---

# Introduction

```{bash echo=FALSE}
perl -le 'print for 1..50'
```
````

If you want it just for code / result snippets I would suggested you place appropriate `\begin{Large}` and `\end{Large}` around it.  I *have* in the past customized the default environments used here --- as I recall knitr more or less follows Sweave here.  Just look at the generated .tex file.

Comment: Aha, the `\begin{size}` mechanism should work well for me, thanks.

Comment: Actually, I haven't gotten the size environment to work.  It seems to remove the `verbatim` environment, then that causes syntax errors for LaTeX.  However, I can do something similar by using `\small ... \normalsize` around my code/result snippet.

Comment: Try peeking at the generated .tex file and look for the "framed" environment.  I keep seeing hints that eg `fontsize=small` can be added.  Sorry, don't seem to have a ready-example I can quote from.